# Magento 2 auto backup is not working

Tags: magento2, backup

I want magento 2 to backup automatically.I have set all the things suggested on https://www.humcommerce.com/tutorial/schedule-backups-in-magento-2 .
But it is not working and not creating any backup for me.Maybe it is not creating cron job for backup.Please let me know what I am missing or suggest if there are any additional steps to create auto backup.Or how can I debug at my end.

Comment: refer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#create-the-cron-job

Comment: Will this set auto backup cron job also?

Comment: It will setup the  cron, based on the job schedule your backup will be done accordingly.

Comment: Where to save the file?

Comment: I am getting error syntax error : redirection unexpected

Comment: Last syntax error is fixed but magento is not creating backup still.

Comment: try to debug, whether cron is running or not

Comment: In the crontab -l it is showing the job in list.

Comment: add a log file, to check the schedule of cron

Comment: By the way I want to know where I have to save the file created in very first step.

Comment: you mean the backup ? the backup will be under your /var/backups/ directory

Comment: how can i check if cron job is doing its work

Comment: Truncate the cron_schedule table and see if it gets re-populated with scheduled tasks after a few minutes.

Comment: I have checked in cron_schedule Field values are

| schedule_id | job_code| status | messages| created_at| scheduled_at|executed_at| finished_at|

1318 | ddg_automation_campaign| missed | Too late for the schedule| 2019-01-17 07:52:14 | 2019-01-17 07:55:00 | NULL| NULL|

Comment: truncate the table, if new entries generating then that mean cron working

Comment: I think your cron is working now, based on this 2019-01-17 07:52:14 | 2019-01-17 07:55:00 | NULL| NULL|

Comment: ??????????????????

Comment: But it is not creating backup

Comment: Is there any other way to create magento 2.2.2 automatically backup

Comment: Bash Script: Easily Backup your Magento2 Code Files + Database php /path/to/magento2/bin/magento setup:backup -v --code --media --db

Comment: Not one time I want to do it automatically daily or weekly.

Comment: Magento 2 having the best automatic backup system, set the time according to your server time and wait for it.maybe it take time depend on the size

Comment: Already done but it is not working

Comment: Truncate the cron_schedule table and see if it gets re-populated with scheduled tasks after a few minutes.

Comment: May I see any log if m2's default backup will not work.

Comment: If i am running sudo php bin/magento cron:run
It is also not creating backup

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected 
Getting this error in the /var/mail/ubuntu

Comment: If i am running sudo php bin/magento cron:run, what error it shows ?

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected Getting this error in the /var/mail/ubuntu

Comment: great..good job (y)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88438/discussion-on-question-by-charanjeet-magento-2-auto-backup-is-not-working).